# Typescript React Native navigation.push incorrect typing

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation

In my react native app, I'm using @react-navigation/native-stack.

The following line gives an error:

```
navigation.push('ScreenName', {myParam});
```

The error is:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '[string, { myParam: string; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[any, string | number | symbol] | [any, string | number | symbol, any, any]'
```

This code does work and is how the documentation specifies it should be done. What should I do to make typescript think it's right?

Edit: My code

```
export default function Home({navigation}: NativeStackScreenProps<any>) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button onPress={() => navigation.push('ScreenName', {myParam: 'stuff'})} title={'Go to ScreenName'}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: did to give type navigation cosnt ? or how are you getting this navigation can you share code?

Comment: @Xhirazi added code

Comment: Specify correct type instead of `any`

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code.

```html
export default function Home({navigation} : {navigation: StackNavigationProp<any, any>}) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button onPress={() => navigation.push('ScreenName', {myParam: 'stuff'})} title={'Go to ScreenName'}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```